# May I take a parcel as my "personal item"?

Tags: luggage, low-cost-carriers, allegiant-air

Due to [the baggage restrictions by Allegiant Air](https://www.allegiantair.com/baggage-info), I am pretty sure I can't declare my 30L backpack as the "free personal item" (16"x15"x7"). Nonetheless, I may be able to compress the backpack along with some clothes into an appropriately sized parcel. I have actually never seen someone doing this, therefore I am asking if this may lead to check-in difficulties.

Comment: `16x15x7` of what? cm? ft? in?

Comment: @pnuts: I mean put it in the question, not the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a problem.  I've taken all sorts of weirdly shaped items in the past (including a full stereo system in shopping bags!), and as long as you meet their criteria, ie:

- no explosives or other banned substances
- no blades or other banned items
- fits their width x height x depth restrictions
- weighs less than their weight limits

then you'll be fine taking it aboard.

Saying that, measure the backpack first - I'm taking a 30L pack on a flight again today and it's actually small enough to fit into most airlines' carry-on limits.

EDIT: Now that their site is working for me, I can see there's actually a FAQ about this on that link above:

> I carry a big purse. Will I be charged a fee to bring that on board
>   or can it count as my personal item?

Which sorta covers your question - basically will something large be too large? And they respond..

> All carry-on and personal items must fit within Allegiant’s luggage
>   dimensions and may be verified prior to boarding.  Please measure your
>   bags carefully, including exterior wheels, pockets, and decoration.
>
> Personal items which do not fit completely underneath a seat may be
>   considered a carry-on bag and passengers will be charged accordingly. 
>   Excess and oversize bags may be gate checked.
>
> The personal item must not exceed exterior dimensions of 7 in. x 15
>   in. x 16 in. (17.8 cm x 38.1 cm x 40.6 cm) and must be placed under
>   the seat. The carry-on bag’s exterior dimensions must not exceed 9 in.
>   x 14 in. x 22 in. (22.9 cm x 35.6 cm x 55.9 cm).

So as expected, as long as your 'personal item', whatever it is, meets their requirements, you should be fine.

Comment: The height of my 30L is (with or without handles) about 2 to 3 inches over the limit of 16 inches. And I expect the low-cost carrier to measure precisely because they want me to pay an additional 50$.

Comment: @user2084795 that's a nuisance, my pack must be more compact. in that case, yeah, my answer still applies - compressing it or whatever into any shape is fine, as long as you meet their luggage restrictions and requirements.

Comment: @pnuts he's mentioned the site above with limits of 15x7x16? are you getting it from somewhere else?

Comment: Oh I misread your comment as that measurement being for personal items.  I follow now :)